# Android consumindo web service soap

Tags: java, android, soap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para buscar no servidor resposta, eu envio o número do boleto e o seu tipo. Só que quando mando os dados ele não me manda um retorno, o que posso estar fazendo de errado?

```
package br.com.testes.webservicesoapxml;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Runnable {
private EditText edtSequencia;
private EditText edtTipo;
private Button buttonOk;
private TextView txtResultado;
private String chaveIntegracao = "sL8xlbkw2454kLx3i803981804000107Lxd5yV063sKc3gHx9344";
private Handler handler = new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtSequencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSequencia);
    edtTipo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTipo);
    buttonOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    txtResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);

    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Thread t = new Thread();
    t.start();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    int sequencia = Integer.parseInt(edtSequencia.toString());
    String tipo = edtTipo.toString();

    WebService ws = new WebService();

    try {
      ws.enviaLinhaDigitavel(this.chaveIntegracao, sequencia, tipo);


        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Erro", e);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Erro", e);
    }


}
}

package br.com.testes.webservicesoapxml;

import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by rodri on 26/09/2016.
 */

public class WebService {


    public String enviaLinhaDigitavel(String chaveIntegracao, int sequencia, String tipo) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        SoapObject soap = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile", "EnviarLinhaDigitavel");
        soap.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao",chaveIntegracao);
        soap.addProperty("Sequencia", sequencia);
        soap.addProperty("tipo", tipo);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE("http://177.8.248.43:81/routerbox/ws_mobile/rbx_server_mobile.php?wsdl");


        Log.i("DEVMEDIA", "Chamando WebService para consulta de CEP");


        httpTransportSE.call("CadastrarAuteticacao",envelope);

        Object resultado = envelope.getResponse();


        return resultado.toString();
    }
}

  Esse é o serviço que estou trabalhando.

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="EnviaLinhaDigitavel">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <env:EnviaLinhaDigitavel soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <Autenticacao xsi:type="urn:Autenticacao" xmlns:urn="urn:RouterSistemas">
            <ChaveIntegracao xsi:type="xsd:string"></ChaveIntegracao>
         </Autenticacao>
         <DadosBoleto xsi:type="urn:DadosBoleto" xmlns:urn="urn:RouterSistemas">
            <Sequencia xsi:type="xsd:int">191</Sequencia>
            <Enviar xsi:type="xsd:string">N</Enviar>
         </DadosBoleto>
      </env:EnviaLinhaDigitavel>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Retorna algum erro ?

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro Não esta retornado nada!

Comment: Estranho, testei seu envelope no endereço e está retornando corretamente eu acho, você chegou a ver o envelope gerado com os métodos do Ksoap se ficou igual ao esperado ? Se sim, pode ser algum problema com a conexão em si

Comment: Coloque alguns breakpoints no seu código (principalmente no resultado.toString();) e verifique no debugger se o objeto resultado está realmente nulo, as vezes é algo no getResponse() ou no próprio toString()

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, estou começando a poucos dias no desenvolvimento android. fiz uma depuração mais não consigo ver o que vem no resultado, como eu posso pegar o resultado que está vindo do resultado e colocar no TextView? O Envelope eu testei pelo SoapUI ele funciona. deve  estar fazendo algo errado no codigo.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, na linha do Resultado aparece isso Suspend thread.

Comment: Ao clicar ao lado do número da linha você adiciona um Breakpoint, se você colocar um breakpoint após uma ação, na janela de depuração você consegue ver a variável e se clicar nela vê tudo que ela possuí, assim da pra ver se a resposta está recebendo algo.

Comment: Esse erro Suspend Thread pode ocorrer ao tentar fazer uma chamada de internet na Thread principal, você está fazendo isso sem nenhuma chamada assíncrona ?

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, está sem chamada assíncrona.

Comment: A partir da API 3 você não consegue fazer chamadas à internet na Thread principal, vou postar uma resposta com um exemplo e você move sua chamada pra dentro do método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente mover sua chamada para uma chamada assíncrona:

```
public String enviaLinhaDigitavel(String chaveIntegracao, int sequencia, String tipo) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        SoapObject soap = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile", "EnviarLinhaDigitavel");
        soap.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao",chaveIntegracao);
        soap.addProperty("Sequencia", sequencia);
        soap.addProperty("tipo", tipo);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE("http://177.8.248.43:81/routerbox/ws_mobile/rbx_server_mobile.php?wsdl");






new AsyncTask<Void,String,String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
               Log.i("DEVMEDIA", "Chamando WebService para consulta de CEP");


        httpTransportSE.call("CadastrarAuteticacao",envelope);

        Object resultado = envelope.getResponse();


        return resultado.toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
               // faça alguma coisa com seu retorno
            }
        }.execute();

}
```

A única coisa que precisa prestar atenção, é que seu método não retornará mais a string, você precisa passar o resultado no método `onPostExecute()`, é melhor dar uma pesquisada em como funciona uma AsyncTask

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, irei fazer as mudanças e fazer os testes.